remove Everyone and Everyone Except External Users from all places in an SPO Sites
Requirement:
One of our Clients is working on correcting permissions on there tenant and thus needs to remove "Everyone" and "Everyone except external users" from identified places like at root level, at list/library and at item level.
Info Available
We have the URL paths for items/list/sites where these groups are added in an excel
Challenge
This excel only contains the path like below and does not have have any identifier to check if its a site URL, a list library URL or an item URL
https://DomaiName.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC
https://DomaiName.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/Documents
https://DomaiName.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/Documents/folder
https://DomaiName.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/Documents/folder/file
I need help in developing a script to remove the above groups from these location.

Please check if your documents library is inheriting the permissions from the site? If yes, then just remove everyone from the SharePoint groups at site level will work form you.

Thanks @DikeshGandhi I was able to create the script for Site, List/Library and Item level, however I also need to remove access from Sharing links as well. Do you have any Idea about this. I tries the suggestion in the below article but it removes the user from entire site collection and we just want to remove users access from shared links only:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/08/how-to-remove-shared-links-in-sharepoint-online.html

For sharing links, I suggest you to raise a new question with script chunk you tried so far. So community people will review and help you quickly.

Please add your script in the answer and accept the answer so it will helpful to others.
